PHP regex find video or audio all occurences
I have this regex:
$str = '<video controls src="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2024/08/lip_mask.mp4"></video><video controls src="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/09.mp4"></video><audio controls src="http://localhost/xampp/wp/wp-content/uploads/2024/07/01.mp3"></audio>';

preg_match_all('/<video[^>]+src="([^"]+)")/', $str, $matches);

preg_match_all('/<audio[^>]+src="([^"]+)")/', $str, $matches);

It works individually, but when I try to combine them, I am not getting desired results
preg_match_all('/(<video[^>]+src="([^"]+)")|(<audio[^>]+src="([^"]+)")/', $str, $matches);

Point is to get all occurences in order they appear. I though about using loop and checking one, then another, but then I would need to modify and remove string after match.

Why not like <(?:audio|video)\b[^>]+src="([^"]+)" See https://regex101.com/r/XeSszx/1

Use a html parser to parse html

Topically relevant: Find  tag with specific style declarations then return the src value of its child  tag and How to extract img src, title and alt from html using php?  Bad regex advice found here: regular expression to match src attribute value within a video tag

There is no sample input and no desired output. This question is missing its [mcve].
